# Sequelize: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

Currently using ExpressJS as the framework to create a small CMS system but currently running into a problem. I am trying to create a model for a table called 'roles' but when I add it to my database file to be included, I get the following error once I run 'node app.js'

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.mapValueFieldNames (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:232:19)
    at Promise.try.then.then (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2393:37)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Ryahn\Documents\Projects\monkeys\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

If I do not include the model in the database init file, it runs just fine. The idea is to then use a relationship to pair the two. I do not plan on having permissions assigned, just using roles. The migration file is setup the same as the model. I was assuming by matching how the user model was setup, the roles model would work as well. But now I am unsure what is going on.

**Users**

```
'use strict';
const
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    bcrypt = Promise.promisifyAll(require('bcrypt'))
    ;
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const users = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            notEmpty: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            notEmpty: true
        },
        role: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(2).UNSIGNED,
            validate: {
                isNumeric: true
            }
        },
        steamid: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(17),
            validate: {
                len: 17
            }
        },
        link: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            validate: {
                isUrl: true
            }
        },
        last_login: DataTypes.DATE
    }, 
    {
        hooks: {

            beforeCreate: function(user, options) {
                if (!user.changed('password')) {
                    return sequelize.Promise.reject('not modified');
                }

                return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hash => {
                    return user.password = hash;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return sequelize.Promise.reject(err);
                });
            },

            beforeUpdate: function(user, options) {
                if (!user.changed('password')) {
                    return sequelize.Promise.reject('not modified');
                }

                return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(hash => {
                    return user.password = hash;
                }).catch(err => {
                    return sequelize.Promise.reject(err);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    users.prototype.generateHash = function(password) {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
    };

    users.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    };

    users.sync({force: false}).then(() => {
        return users.findOrCreate({
            where: {
                id: 1,
                username: 'Admin'
            },
            defaults: {
                username: 'Admin',
                password: 'admin123',
                role: 1,
                steamid: parseInt(12345678901234567),
                link: 'https://www.example.com/user_profile.php?userID=1171981'
            }
        });
    });

    return users;
};
```

**Roles**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const roles = sequelize.define('roles', {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        slug: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    let role = [];
    role.push([
        { name: 'Admin', slug: 'admin'},
        { name: 'Staff', slug: 'staff'},
        { name: 'Trainer', slug: 'trainer'},
        { name: 'Captain', slug: 'captain'},
        { name: 'Monkey', slug: 'monkey'}
    ]);
    roles.sync({force: false}).then(() => {
        return roles.bulkCreate(role);
    });

    return roles;
};
```

**Init**

```
const 
    config = require('../config/database'),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config),
    db = {}
    ;

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.users = require('./models/users')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.roles = require('./models/roles')(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: There should ne raw query above this error , please check that , and also post that over here.

Comment: @VivekDoshi The only raw query I have is in the user controller.
`sequelize.query('SELECT users.*, Roles.* FROM users LEFT JOIN Roles ON users.role = Roles.id', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
        ).then(users => {
            res.render('user/index', { users: users, csrf: req.csrfToken(), moment: moment, hasRole: hasRole, user: req.user });
        });`